# Angular momentum energy loss

Tags: angular-momentum

Suppose a man sits on a freely rotatable light chair holding 2 dumbbells to his chest, he then extends his hands while maintaining the height of each dumbbells (so that gravitational of the system is constant). His angular speed is reduced while his moment of inertia increases.

Where did the lost energy go?

(I do know numerical proof that energy do loss, but I wanted to know how and where did the energy go, any proofs by any formulas of physics is appreciated)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The reverse motion is easier to understand, assume he first has his arms stretched, and then pulls the weight to the center.
What happened? He did work. The man feels centrifugal force, and against this force (which is not constant, so you cannot just calculate $W=F\cdot s$) he does work.

Now the other direction of the motion is less intuitive. Because, unfortunately, humans are not good in gaining work by letting the system do work on them. Or in other words, in capturing potential energy like a spring - otherwise you could jump without having to do the whole work every jump.

But nevertheless, the work is done by the dumbbells on the arms of the human - the force on the hand is in the direction of motion, it could gain energy if it were a spring.

Comment: So according to your answers, the human loses energy while the dumbbells are gaining but human loses more than the amount dumbbells are gaining due to work against centrifugal force? Another question, due to centrifugal force is fictitious, can it be said that it is centripetal force that does the work, but in opposite directions?

Comment: No, that doesn't sound right. The work against the centrifugal force **is** the transmitted energy from the man to the dumbbell. That's not what one calls "loss". Some energy is lost, because the muscles have a low efficiency (they get hot, they can't just contract).

Comment: And energy is lost in the other direction, when the weight does work on the arm. The human cannot make any use of this work. This also is lost - just as in the case of jumping you cannot retain the energy you had before landing and use it to jump up again

Comment: And, again, the centripetal force **is** the force from the man on the dumbbell. So if motion is inwards, then the work (on the dumbbell) is positive, and if motion is outward, then contrary the dumbbell does work on the arm - which cannot make use of it

Comment: So by your explanations, if the arms are now replaced by a pair of springs that can gain energy by being worked on, will the energy of the system remains constant?

Comment: yes, it will accumulate in the potential energy of the springs; or rather, the length of the spring will pass the equilibrium position and there will be an oscillation (of the length of the spring *and* the angular velocity). So it's better to replace the arms by a machine that will use that energy. Of course, it will never be 100%; but in the case of the human it's 0%

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, what about replacing arms with ropes so that they  can not do any work and the dumbell slip outward from the center by themselves, in this case, where did the energy go?

Comment: You mean bungee jumping :) - There is again nothing special about the rotating system, just the same problem as if you let a weight fall and then be suddenly stopped by a rope. Or fall on the ground, thats also similar to falling in the rope. There is an inelastic colision. The energy is lost, in heat eventually. The rope can do work - in the end - when it is already stretched ($F$) but still expands a bit ($ds$)